# Stylus multiple loop iterators

Tags: stylus

Is it possible to implement something like this in Stylus?

```
for $i in 1..5 and $n in a b c d e
  .icon-{$i}:before{
    content: $n 
  }
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at mixins http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/iteration.html

Comment: did you even think about the question you just asked? did you even try to solve it on your own?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: yes.

---

and here is how: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jIbdq

```
icon_contents = ( "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" )

for v, k in icon_contents
  .icon-{k+1}:before
    content v
```